# How to parser string with BRT time zone abbreviation in PHP

Tags: php, datetime, php-carbon

I have different strings in different time zones:
2019-11-13 00:52:03 ADT
2019-11-13 00:52:03 EET
**2019-11-13 00:52:03 BRT**

I use format `Y-m-d H:i:s T` with `DateTime::createFromFormat` to get date time object.

But the next code returns FALSE:
`DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s T', '2019-11-13 00:52:03 BRT')`

**Problem:** PHP doesn't recognise **BRT** abbreviation time zone.

Is there any way to overcome this?
For example, can I add new abbreviation to PHP time zones list?

P.S.

```php
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
    echo date_default_timezone_get();
    echo ' => '.date('T');
```

Returns `America/Sao_Paulo => -03`

Comment: Please refer to the PHP docs: https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetimezone.listabbreviations.php

Comment: The issue is my strings have BRT abbreviation time zone. I don't know which string what time zone has. It can be BRT, it can be any other abbreviation.

Comment: Where are the date strings coming from? Do you read them from file, DB or...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot add new timezone abbreviations to PHP. PHP gets these timezones from the built in timezone database, which is based on the [Olson Database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database).

You can, however, provide literals in `DateTime::createFromFormat` by escaping them with the backslash character. So in your case you will need to set the timezone manually if it fails. You can test if the timezone abbreviation doesn't match anything in the database by using `DateTimezone::listAbbreviations()`.

Here's an example...

```php
$defaultTZ = null;
$tzString = "2019-11-13 00:52:03 BRT";
$tzs = implode('|', array_keys(DateTimeZone::listAbbreviations()));

if (!preg_match("/(?: )(" . $tzs . ")$/i", $tzString)) {
    if (preg_match("/(?: )([A-Z]{3,4})$/", $tzString, $match)) {
        $tzAbr = "\\" . implode("\\", str_split($match[1]));
        $defaultTZ = new DateTimezone("America/Sao_Paulo");
    } else {
        // ohnoes something went horribly wrong
    }
} else {
    $tzAbr = "T";
}

$date = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d H:i:s $tzAbr", $tzString, $defaultTZ);

var_dump($date);
```

Which gives you...

```
object(DateTime)#2 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2019-11-13 00:52:03.000000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(17) "America/Sao_Paulo"
}
```

You will have to work out your own logic for how you handle unspecified timezones, but that should give you an idea of how to proceed from here.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, this could work if I only need to parse string with 1 time zone. But I have a lot of strings in different time zones. And I don't know which string what time zone abbreviation has.

Comment: @tolek you can always check if your timezone string ends in BRT and do this parsing only in that case. The other timezones (hopefully) are correctly included in the database

Comment: @apokryfos yes, this will work. I was hoping there can be more elegant solution :)

Comment: @tolek Please see my updated answer. This should handle all cases where the timezone abbreviation is not listed in the database. However, you will have to work out your own logic for how to deal with such unspecified timezones.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to replace unsuported timezone with matching supported time zone or offset before converting string to DateTime object.

```
$date = "2019-11-13 00:52:03 America/Sao_Paulo";
$dateTime = new DateTime($date);
print_r($dateTime);

$date = "2019-11-13 00:52:03 -0300";
$dateTime = new DateTime($date);
print_r($dateTime);

$date = "2019-11-13 00:52:03";
$dateTime = new DateTime($date, new DateTimeZone('-0300'));
print_r($dateTime);
```